# My phone got factory reset and all data wiped, can I find out how?

Tags: factory-reset, restore, htc-one

Today morning after a long taxi ride (I am travelling this week, personal vacation), I took my phone from my pocket and it seemed to be turned off. I switched it on and the phone started up as it was the first time.

All my settings, config, apps, widgets were gone. I think the phone was factory reset. Not sure if it was locally (accidental click in settings?) or may be remotely. (The phone *was* fine earlier in the morning).

I tried to get the data from my Google account backup (which I remember setting up when I got this phone) but I could not (no 'Restore' option was enabled in settings. But that would be a different question).
I had to manually (painfully) set up things again. All my photos are backed up to google and I think I can get them back. Same for apps, most of the should have data on the cloud somewhere.

Is there a way to know what happened?

I have a HTC one (M7), and use Google for most services including backups.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think you could get to know what has made your device getting factory reset on its own. As far as I know I think somehow the volume up and power keys may have been pressed which results in factory reset. I have also heard the if you put the patter lock wrong over the HTC M8 for more that 10 times, the device gets automatically factory reset. I am sure Accidently you may have !!

Comment: The 10 times is a possibility. I was hoping there would be some log of why this happened, but I understand the log would also have been deleted. May be there are beat practices around how to backup a device....

Answer (score 1):

Several options:

- You had an exchange email account (probably corporate) which had device admin permissions, and it got activated by the email provider.
- You had android device manager installed and somebody activated the factory reset
- Or you reset it by unluckily booting the device into boot loader, opening recovery and factory resetting (as suggested by @peter carlos)

Comment: All of this could have happened. Thanks for the feedback. Now off to investigate why backup recovery did not work.

Comment: Which backup recovery, because the default google one just backs up links to play store apps and any data stored in play games.